# Removing object from collection, using the Java mongo driver

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my sample code:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");

BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject("$search", "mytextsearch");
BasicDBObject textSearch = new BasicDBObject("$text", search);

BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("score", new BasicDBObject("$meta",   "textScore"));
myDoc = coll.findOne(textSearch, projection);
```

This should find the document, I call it myDoc, with the highest score for searching "mytextsearch".

Then, I want to remove this document from the collection, so I did:

```
coll.remove(myDoc);
```

However, this has no effect on the collection, and myDoc is never deleted. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to delete myDoc after I have found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remove-method does not remove the document you pass to it. It removes all documents which have all fields in common with the `DBObject` passed. Why is this distinction important in this case? Because you are using a projection to change the document.

After the projection, the DBObject has a new field `textScore=something`. When you then pass that DBObject to `.remove()`, the database will only delete a document which also has a field `textScore` with that exact value. Because the original document in the collection hasn't got this field, it doesn't get deleted.

So what do you do instead?

Create a new `BasicDBObject` with only the `_id` of the document you want to delete and nothing else. Because the `_id` field is always unique and automatically indexed, this will be both unambiguous and fast. Then pass this one to `.remove`.

Comment: Too bad I do not yet have a 15 reputation, or I would have given you a +1. Thank you for the very clear answer.